# Freya "forgets" keyboard shortcut after reboot

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I have a problem with the shortcut for switching the keyboard layout, which is "Alt+Space" as per default.

I have to set it manually for each single session, meaning that right after I boot up Freya the shortcut doesn't do anything and I have to go to the keyboard settings and manually set "Alt+Space" as the shortcut for either "Switch to next layout" or "Switch to previous layout", depending on which of those was bound to "Alt+Space" in the previous session.

After that the shortcut starts working again, but once I reboot the system, Freya seems not to recognize it anymore. Strangely, I never had this problem on my other machine, which also runs Freya.